# React JS Toggle for showing additional info about contacts

Tags: reactjs

I've just started to learn React and trying to implement toggle effect in Contacts list, that should show additional info about contact, when you click on it.

Current code is following:

```
  var CONTACTS = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Darth Vader',
        phoneNumber: '+250966666666',
        image: 'img/darth.gif',
        email: 'vader@deathstar.com',
        address: 'Death Star'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Princess Leia',
        phoneNumber: '+250966344466',
        image: 'img/leia.gif',
        email: 'leia@skywalker.com',
        address: 'Naboo'
    }
];

var Contact = React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function () {
      return {
        isOpened : false
      };
    },

    toggleState : function () {
      this.setState({
        isOpened: !this.state.isOpened
      });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
                <li className="contact" onClick={this.toggleState}>
                    <img className="contact-image" src={this.props.image} width="60px" height="60px" />
                    <div className="contact-info">
                        <div className="contact-name"> {this.props.name} </div>
                        <div className="contact-number"> {this.props.phoneNumber} </div>
                        <div> {this.state.isOpened} </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
        );
    }
});
```

How can I set isOpened equal to contact address and email to show it when toggle is triggered? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change

```
<div> {this.state.isOpened} </div>
```

to

```
{
    this.state.isOpened ?
        <div>
            <div className="contact-email"> {this.props.email} </div>
            <div className="contact-address"> {this.props.address} </div>
        </div>
        :
        null
}
```

What that does is show the divs with the email and address if `this.state.isOpened` is true. Otherwise returns null (an empty UI)

Then, you can change the state using a checkbox, toggle button or any other toggling control (which basically calls your `toggleState` method).

For example, using a checkbox (any where in your page):

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.isOpened} onChange={this.toggleState} />
```